# How to allow users to select "no dates" (zero value)?

Tags: input

I am working on a project where I report time on different project like this: 
[image]

I check the dates, and I select the project I want to report the time onto.
It's all good, but what if I do not have any time report for one day?

Right now I have it setup so I have a project called "No Time To Report" And I choose that project and put 8 hours onto that.

But if the issue with that is it will show up in my monthly summary. It will show up like I did work 8 hours on that project, while I did not work at all. 
Like this:
[image]

I guess I could hard code it so that "No Time To Report" project doesn't show up in any list and it doesn't count the hours on that project. But would that be such a good thing to do?

Comment: Why are you asking people to manually enter what is essentially a null value? If there's no time to enter, then don't have them enter anything; in my opinion, it would be implied that there was no time to report.

Comment: @Brian Because it's a foreach loop that loops out all the dates the user have not reported for, so if I do not have to report a date for a month the date will just be there and taking up space.

Comment: what is the problem with selecting "No Project" and then not reporting the hours for "No Project" in the sum-of-all-projects report?

Comment: How do I select the date for which I am providing the details ?

Answer (score 1):

**Let them enter no dates, but confirm the choice.**

Instruct the user to complete the form as usual. If they select no dates, hit them with a modal dialog.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flfxKR.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Also, the list of the ~30 checkboxes to select dates is far from the best design here.

**Allow users to select from a date picker.**

A calendar style date picker would be the conventional and expected choice of UI control here. It allows users to more easily parse the previous month, visualize weekends, etc.

Here's a multi-date picker for jQuery, but there are lots out there.

http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The reason the dates are displayed like that is due it's the date I've forgotten to report a time for. Not sure how that would work in a DatePicker. I can't just disable some dates from if I believe.

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson There are date pickers that support disabling or enabling only the dates you choose, for example [react-day-picker](http://react-day-picker.js.org/). The disabled days are displayed with gray text instead of black text in the month view.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to mark the time down to an "Overhead" line item.  "Overhead" is all activity that cannot be billed to a specific project, thus sick days, dental appointments, "mental health days", general research, doodling, annual holiday, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would enter time and then add it to "no time to report"? Is this some accounting thing where all hours need to be accounted for in the end, and you just need to split un-billable hours from billable ones? In that case I'd expect there to be an "Overhead" project to be used for that. After all, in the end someone still pays for those hours (even if it's your employer with your monthly wage).

If that's not the case, what one usually does is to put a check box in front of items that may be left out. You can deactivate that check box to indicate "no value" or "no change". Take older versions of iTunes, for example, where you could select multiple tracks, and then chose which properties to bulk-edit by checking the ones you want to change.

PS - as others have pointed out, the checkboxes are awkward and complicated UI. Usually you'd either have a text field where people can enter a date, (this is useful when people frequently use your UI, because typing one key is faster than moving a mouse and clicking for each day once you're acquainted with the workflow), or you provide a calendar where people can select days.

If there's some CSS magic you plan to do to turn the checkboxes into a calendar, be sure to permit drag-selecting multiple days & keyboard entering of a date.